# If $X$ is separable, then so is its subset

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, separable-spaces

> Let $(X,\|\cdot \|)$ be a normed space and $M\subseteq X$. Show that
> if $X$ is separable, then $M$ is separable.

---

My attempt:

Since $X$ is separable $\Leftrightarrow$ $\exists E\subset X:$ $E$ is dense and countable.

We need to show that $M$ is separable. I'll do this by proving that the intersection $E\cap M =:V\subseteq M$ is countable and dense in $M$. It's clear that it's countable since $V\subseteq E$ and $E$ is countable.

Remains to show: $V$ is dense ($\Leftrightarrow V\cap O\neq \emptyset$ $\forall O\subseteq M$ open). Because $O\cap E\neq \emptyset$ (Because $E$ is dense), we have that
$$O\cap E \overset{O\subseteq M}{=} O\cap (E\cap M) = O\cap V \neq \emptyset$$

Therefore, M is also separable.

---

My problem now is that I probably need $M$ to be open for this proof to work? If so, how can I fix this so that it holds true for any subset $M$?

Comment: Most proofs use the fact that a metric space is seperable iff it is second countable (i.e., has a countable neighborhood basis) and that a subset of a second countable space is also second countable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please notice that there's no reason for $E\cap M$ to be different from the empty set. So let $E=\{x_n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, then you can write
$$X=\bigcup_{n,m} B\Big(x_n,\frac{1}{m}\Big)$$
Consider now all the pairs $(n,m)$ for which $M\cap B\Big(x_n,\frac{1}{m}\Big)\neq\emptyset$ and for each such pair select $a_{n,m}\in M\cap B\Big(x_n,\frac{1}{m}\Big)$, then now the collection $\tilde{E}=\{a_{n,m}\mid n,m\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is your candidate countable dense subset of $M$. Notice the density comes immediately from the definition of $a_{n,m}$ which belongs to a dense set (i.e. $E$)

Comment: Nice answer but could you maybe explain why $X = \cup_{n,m} B(x_n, 1/m)$? I see why you could do this but if I can take any $m\in \mathbb{N}$ then the open ball might be larger than $X$? So I need the right selection of $m$'s, correct?

Comment: Since $X$ has a dense subset and It is a normed space, $X$ is 2nd countable as already started in the comments. So now, we can take countable open balls and decide th radius of each to be arbitrarely small, notice It doesn't really matter how small you take It. Moreover we are using a decreasing sequence, hence at worst scenario you should pick all $m$'s from a certain $\bar{m}$ on.